# exe file not found with which after setting the Path

Tags: terminal, catalina, path

I need to have an exe file found in the terminal with "which FILE" command. I set the PATH to this file but I cannot find the file with which?

I added

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/MSM_old/msm_mac
```

in `~/.zprofile`. `msm_mac` is the binary.

When I type in which msm or msm_mac, the result is msm not found.

Current value of the PATH:

```
/Users/neurolab/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/neurolab/opt/anaconda3/condabin://Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/freesurfer/bin://Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/freesurfer/fsfast/bin://Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/freesurfer/tktools:/Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/fsl/bin://Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/freesurfer/mni/bin:/Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/fsl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/spjder:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/workbench/bin_macosx64i:/Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/MSM_old/msm_mac
```

I am using MBP 2019 with Catalina

What can I do?

Best,

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` is a list of *directories* so need to add

```
/Users/neurolab/Desktop/Stephan/Programmes/MSM_old
```

to your PATH (and re-read `~/.zprofile`) to make it work.

Comment: thanks. It’s a good idea and does absolutely not hurt to revise the basics .. at least from time to time ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot!
I added only the the directory path but it is still the same. What you mean by re-read?

Comment: @Dr.S Open a new tab in Terminal, or run `source ~/.zprofile`.